# why dividing by a constant an xts object in R results in a matrix object (losing the Date column)?

Tags: r, type-conversion, xts

thanks for any help regarding:

why dividing by a constant an xts object in R results in a matrix object (the Date/index column is lost)?
I would expect that the resulting object would be an xts object, like the input xts, with just the column values divided by the constant. Why this happens and how to avoid it?

Example of the problem that I observe.

Code extract:

```
TradeProfit <- as.xts(ifelse(is.na(lag(GLD$Signal, 1)) == 0 & GLD$Signal != lag(GLD$Signal, 1), GLD$TotTradCapital, NA ))
TradeProfit <- na.omit(TradeProfit)

TradeProfitPerc <- ifelse(is.na(lag(TradeProfit,1)) == 0, TradeProfit / 100, NA)
TradeProfitPerc <- na.omit(TradeProfitPerc)

> class(TradeProfit)
[1] "xts" "zoo"

> head(TradeProfit)
              Signal
2012-08-15  0.000000
2012-11-02  6.970001
2012-11-06  6.970001
2013-08-09 46.410003
2013-08-14 46.410003
2013-09-27 46.380004

head(TradeProfitPerc)
        Signal
[1,] 0.06970001
[2,] 0.06970001
[3,] 0.46410003
[4,] 0.46410003
[5,] 0.46380004
[6,] 0.46380004

> class(TradeProfitPerc)
[1] "matrix"
>
```

The problem is that TradeProfitPerc looses the Date column/index which I want to retain. Also as TradeProfit is an xts object why the division causes such a strange behavior transforming an xts into a matrix object? How can I keep the xts properties? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a minimal, reproducible example:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("GLD")
GLD$GLD.SMA <- SMA(Cl(GLD), 50)
GLD$Signal <- Cl(GLD) > GLD$GLD.SMA

TradeProfit <- as.xts(ifelse(!is.na(lag(GLD$Signal, 1)) &
                             GLD$Signal != lag(GLD$Signal, 1), 100, NA))
TradeProfit <- na.omit(TradeProfit)

TradeProfitPerc <- ifelse(!is.na(lag(TradeProfit,1)), TradeProfit / 100, NA)
TradeProfitPerc <- na.omit(TradeProfitPerc)
```

The problem is that calling `is.na` on an xts object results in a logical matrix with no row names, and `ifelse` returns an object with the same shape and attributes as its first argument.  So `TradeProfitPerc` is a matrix with no row names because that's the structure of the first argument passed to `ifelse`.

This isn't a problem when calculating `TradeProfit` because of the `& GLD$Signal != lag(GLD$Signal, 1)`.  The `GLD$Signal != lag(GLD$Signal, 1)` comparison returns an xts object, and a logical comparison between an xts object and non-xts object yields an xts object.  For example:

```
str(FALSE & xts(TRUE, Sys.Date()))
An 'xts' object on 2017-06-05/2017-06-05 containing:
  Data: logi [1, 1] FALSE
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

You can avoid this by avoiding `ifelse` and subsetting directly:

```
GLD$TotTradCapital <- 500
# rows where Signal is NA will be FALSE and therefore not included in TradeProfit
TradeProfit <- GLD[GLD$Signal != lag(GLD$Signal, 1), "TotTradCapital"]
TradeProfitPerc <- TradeProfit / 100
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua Ulrich for your detailed answer that provides both a solution and the explanation why my code is not working.

Comment: re-reading your answer, could you please also explain why in the case of the variable TradeProfit the is.na() call does not cause the index/date column to be dropped?

Comment: thanks. Now it is clear. I really had not thought and was not aware about the possible change of type while applying functions to an xts object.

Comment: @FilippoNeri: it's a quirk of `ifelse()`, not specific to xts.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would simply add a column to your existing object, which will keep the `xts` class.

```
GLD <- xts(matrix(1:10,ncol=2),Sys.Date()+0:4)
colnames(GLD) <- c("Signal","TotTradCapital")
TradeProfit <- as.xts(ifelse(is.na(lag(GLD$Signal, 1)) == 0 & GLD$Signal != lag(GLD$Signal, 1), GLD$TotTradCapital, NA ))
TradeProfit <- na.omit(TradeProfit)

TradeProfit$TradeProfitPerc <- ifelse(!is.na(lag(TradeProfit,1)), TradeProfit / 100, NA)

           Signal TradeProfitPerc
2017-06-06      7              NA
2017-06-07      8            0.08
2017-06-08      9            0.09
2017-06-09     10            0.10
```

Comment: thanks @PLapointe for taking the time to answer. Yes your solution works. I am however especially trying to understand why my code does not works as to best understand what code works or not with xts and avoid to repeat similar mistakes. So I have to prefer J Ulrich answer below for explaining that is.na returns a logical matrix thus the change of type that I observe in my code above. Thanks!

Comment: @FilippoNeri All good. Joshua is the author of the `xts` package. He knows best.